# Facing issue while configuring PyCharm with QGIS

Tags: python, pycharm, qgis

I am new in QGis and Python as well. I was trying to configure my PyCharm with the interpreter provided for QGIS and also I want to list down all the packages there and install it except qgis-plugin (it gives me the error "error: can't copy 'docs': doesn't exist or not a regular file"). It shows undefined reference. Can you please help me to fix the problem. Here is the code:

```
from qgis.core import *

# supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18", True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

qgs.initQgis()
```

The QgsApplication is showing as undefined reference. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you choose the right interpreter in PyCharm?

Comment: Hey Giordano, I have used right interpreter. I do not have any other interpreter to choose from the list and I can write a standalone python script and that works fine only I believe problem with QGIS Plugin.